# ZBar SDK get freeze while trying open the camera

Tags: ios7

I am Using ZBAR SDK in our app. but while trying  open again and again then ZBarReaderView take more time to alloc in IOS 7 and it get Freeze.

Comment: using `AVFoundation` is much better and smoother solution for detecting different type of barcodes on iOS7+.

Answer (score 0):

[ZBar memory leak on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18638319/zbar-memory-leak-on-ios)

Check this out. I've had this problem myself, and this topic pushed me into a solution.